# AngularJS expressions in "range" input definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I found out, that range input supports only strings in "min" and "max" properties, and more than that, it requires that during it's initialization. Therefore, the following code doesnt work:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="axis in csCtrl.backupConfig.yaxes" ng-init="csCtrl.initAxisValues()">
    <div class="item range range-positive">
        <input type="range" min="{{axis.min}}" max="{{axis.max}}" ng-model="csCtrl.rangesMin[$index]"/>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

The element will initialize, but if axis.max and the value in mg-model equals, for example, 1200, the pointer of the slider will stop at the start, at the value of 100. I think this problem arises, because input element initializes faster than angular assigns a value to min and max.

Here is similar codepen, notice how first range is stopped at the beginning, but the second with explicit string in "max" parameter is working correctly: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kqAlv

Is there any solution? I thought of manually constructing input elements through jQuery, but i'm afraid that this will break angular expressions inside.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ng-if to check if there's a value present in axis.min, this way the dom element will be created when angular assigns a value to it

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="axis in csCtrl.backupConfig.yaxes" ng-init="csCtrl.initAxisValues()">
    <div class="item range range-positive" ng-if="axis.min > 0">
        <input type="range" min="{{axis.min}}" max="{{axis.max}}" ng-model="csCtrl.rangesMin[$index]"/>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: No, sorry, my wording may have been not clear. Of course, I always have valid values in axis.min/axeis.max fields. What I meant is that _expression_ itself may initialize slower than input element. Or maybe I'm pants on head wrong and the problem is somewhere else.